# Flutter：Get the first frame of the video

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How to get the first frame of the local video file in the Flutter project?
Here is my code:

```
ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera).then((File file) {
  if (file != null && mounted) {
    //I got the video file here, but I want to get the first frame of the video.
  }
 });
},
```

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have tried?

Comment: ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera)
                    .then((File file) {
                  if (file != null && mounted) {
                     //I got the video file here, but I want to get the first frame of the video.
                  }
                });
              },

Comment: Kindly add that in your question, it is difficult to analyze code in comment.

Comment: The code is below，please see it

Comment: Try this https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/video_player, and the logic would be to take the thumbnail of the video at 0th second. Personally I have never used this plugin before, so I am not sure what other functions it offer.

Comment: thank u,i will try it!

Answer (score -7, accepted):

```
String thumb = await Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
    thumbnailFolder:'[FOLDER PATH TO STORE THUMBNAILS]', // creates the specified path if it doesnt exist
    videoFile: '[VIDEO PATH HERE]',
    imageType: ThumbFormat.PNG,
    quality: 30);

/*
* thumbnailFolder property can be omitted if you dont wish to keep the generated thumbails past each usage
*/
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation for your code and how this answers the question?

Comment: This answer works only with Android. Flutter main selling point is being cross-platform, if you post a solution please explicitly state it works only halfway.

Answer (score 6):

First, get the file path from File Object and pass it to the below method which uses [video_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) lib for generating thumbnail

```
Future<File> genThumbnailFile(String path) async {
    final fileName = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
      video: path,
      thumbnailPath: (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
      imageFormat: ImageFormat.PNG,
      maxHeight: 100, // specify the height of the thumbnail, let the width auto-scaled to keep the source aspect ratio
      quality: 75,
    );
    File file = File(fileName);
    return file;
  }
```

Second, to use it you need to receive the File object in another method using `await` call, then do `setState()` to update the file.

```
 File file = await genThumbnailFile(filePath);
 setState(() {});
```

**Finally, Use files like**

```
Image.file(file, fit: BoxFit.cover,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`export_video_frame`](https://pub.dev/packages/export_video_frame#-example-tab-), it works for IOS.

```
var duration = Duration(seconds: 1);
var image = await ExportVideoFrame.exportImageBySeconds(widget.file, duration, 0);
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the image to show in a container? I'm new to flutter and it keeps saying ```The argument type 'Future<File>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'```

Comment: If a function is returning a Future<File> then you should use it with 'await'. Or you can add '.then()' to your function call. That way you'll get a File returned from the function. Now to display this inside an image, you can pass this file value to Image.file() widget and pass along height, width and fit for styling the Image.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of view that can be used for this

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:export_video_frame/export_video_frame.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:video_compress/video_compress.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:video_thumbnail/video_thumbnail.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  String thumbNailImage = '';
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/butterfly.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {
          Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
            final byteData =
                await rootBundle.load("assets/videos/butterfly.mp4");
            Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

            File tempVideo = File("${tempDir.path}/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4")
              ..createSync(recursive: true)
              ..writeAsBytesSync(byteData.buffer
                  .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

            final thumbnailFile = await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(
                tempVideo.path,
                quality: 50, // default(100)
                position:
                    (_controller.value.duration.inMilliseconds) // default(-1)
                );

            var duration = _controller.value.duration;
            var image = await ExportVideoFrame.exportImageBySeconds(
                tempVideo, Duration(seconds: 3), 0);

            thumbNailImage = image.path;

            // final fileName = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
            //   video: tempVideo.path,
            //   thumbnailPath: (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
            //   imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
            //   timeMs: _controller.value.duration.inMilliseconds,
            //   maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toInt(),
            //   //quality: 100,
            // );
            //thumbNailImage = fileName!;
            print(
                "file name = $thumbNailImage video duration = ${_controller.value.duration.inMilliseconds}");
            setState(() {});
          });
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: thumbNailImage != ''
          ? Image.file(
              File(thumbNailImage),
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            )
          : Container(), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

And these are packages needed

```
video_player: ^2.1.12
path_provider: ^2.0.2
export_video_frame: ^0.0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code uses the video_thumbnail plugin which shows support for both Android and ios in its documentation

```
Future genThumbnailFile() async{
    final thumbnail = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
        video:
        _video.path,
        // thumbnailPath: _tempDir,
        imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
        //maxHeightOrWidth: 0,
        maxHeight:3,
        maxWidth: 2,
        quality: 10);
    setState(() {
      final file = File(thumbnail);
      filePath = file.path;
    });
  }
```

Then use this filePath variable in the Image widget as follows

```
filePath != null
                      ? Container(
                      width:400,
                      height: 200,
                      child: Image(image: AssetImage(filePath)))
                      : Text('No Floatting Button Click')
```

Answer (score 0):

**in Ios simulator this worked for me**

```
Future<File> genThumbnailFile(ImageModel video) async {
    final path = video.isFile ? video.file!.path : video.url!;
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final bytes = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
      video: path,
      imageFormat: ImageFormat.PNG,
      maxHeight: 70,
      quality: 20,
    );
    final File file = await File('${dir.path}/thumb.png').writeAsBytes(bytes!);
    return file;
  }
```

Answer (score -5):

I implemented this using [thumbnails](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/thumbnails) of pub.

```
String thumb = await Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
    thumbnailFolder:'[FOLDER PATH TO STORE THUMBNAILS]', // creates the specified path if it doesnt exist
    videoFile: '[VIDEO PATH HERE]',
    imageType: ThumbFormat.PNG,
    quality: 30);

/*
* thumbnailFolder property can be omitted if you dont wish to keep the generated thumbails past each usage
*/
```

Comment: Kindly delete this from answer. I updated your question.

Comment: This answer works only with Android. Flutter main selling point is being cross-platform, if you post a solution please explicitly state it works only halfway.